# Apache Virtual Hosts pattern matching

Tags: apache-2.2

I've tried looking at other similar questions, but can't really find what I'm looking for.

I have a server running apache2, and I want all requests for www.foo.tld to serve the pages in  /var/www/foo.tld

For example:

```
www.example.com  -> /var/www/example.com
example.net      -> /var/www/example.net
foobar.co.uk     -> /var/www/foobar.co.uk
www.foobar.co.uk -> /var/www/foobar.co.uk
```

I can't figure out how to do this. I can get it working sometimes with or without the www subdomain, but never with both.

Answer (score 3):

The VirtualDocumentRoot apache directive will do the trick, here is a good explanation : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

Comment: Ah I see. Yes this would be the way to do it.

Comment: How do I get this to work both with and without www subdomain?

Comment: @Blazemore I'd say symlink `www.foobar.co.uk` to `foobar.co.uk`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by creating a file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled-000-Dynamic

And renaming the file 000-default to 001-default.

In this file is the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect www to non-www (class B compliance with no-www)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,L]

  # Remove trailing slashes
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

  # Automatically get the correct folder
  UseCanonicalName Off
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1

</VirtualHost>
```

I changed it slightly: the name www.foobar.com now points to /var/www/foobar which makes it a lot easier.

As well as the dynamic virtual hosts, this also redirects www.foobar.com to foobar.com, and remov